# Weblogic 12c spent several minutes during startup resolving EJB references

Tags: java, weblogic12c, ejb-3.1

The startup of my application takes almost 7 minutes, but more than 4 of them are used by Weblogic to resolve EJB references. I've profiled the startup of the server, and I've found that the time is spent in:

`weblogic.application.naming.EnvUtils.findInfo`

Which is called by:

```
weblogic.application.naming.EjbReferenceResolver.get()
|
 - weblogic.application.naming.EjbReferenceResolver.resolve(ApplicationContextInternal)
 |
  - weblogic.application.naming.EjbReferenceResolver.resolveEjbRef(Collection)
    |
     - weblogic.application.naming.EnvUtils.findInfoByReferenceClass
```

[image]

I don't know, but maybe it's trying to figure out those EJB references, and there's a way to tell it that information in a configuration file, or using annotation, that could improve the startup time.

Any ideas? And please, don't tell me about /dev/random - /dev/urandom, because that doesn't fix anything in this case (already tried).